# Does Flutter have video players for all platforms (iOS, Android, Windows, Linux, MacOS)?

Tags: flutter, dart, video, frame

I have a problem. I need to show **mp4** video from **network** for all possible platforms.

I've used [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player), but it is doesn't work for desktop. I wanted to use [media_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/media_kit), but it doesn't work [out of the box](https://github.com/jeffvli/feishin/issues/99) on desktop.

Another solution that I can accept - use the first frame of this mp4 video. But the problem the same: no tutorials how to do this or packages that works on all platforms.

I want to **show video on all platforms** *OR* **get first frame from video on all paltforms**

Please help me to find solution or say that this is impossible.

P.S. All platforms are Android, iOS, MacOS, Windows, Linux

Comment: Use chewie packge for desktop

Comment: @MobinAnsar, but it is only for `ANDROID`, `IOS`, `WEB` but I need also Windows, Linux, MacOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is also an implementation of media_kit
https://pub.dev/packages/media_kit

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called [flutter_meedu_videoplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_meedu_videoplayer). It supports all the platforms like ANDROID, IOS, LINUX, MACOS, WEB, and WINDOWS.

It is a cross-platform video player that uses video_player for android and ios and web, media_kit for windows and Linux, and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Developer of [package:media_kit](https://github.com/media-kit/media-kit) here.

The package is capable of playing videos & audios on all platforms with good performance & stability. It also has built-in video controls to ease your work.

- Android
- iOS
- macOS
- Windows
- GNU/Linux
- Web

Refer to ["Installation" section of the README](https://github.com/media-kit/media-kit#installation).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:media_kit/media_kit.dart';                      // Provides [Player], [Media], [Playlist] etc.
import 'package:media_kit_video/media_kit_video.dart';          // Provides [VideoController] & [Video] etc.        

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Necessary initialization for package:media_kit.
  MediaKit.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyScreen(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyScreen> createState() => MyScreenState();
}

class MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  // Create a [Player] to control playback.
  late final player = Player();
  // Create a [VideoController] to handle video output from [Player].
  late final controller = VideoController(player);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Play a [Media] or [Playlist].
    player.open(Media('https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28951144/229373695-22f88f13-d18f-4288-9bf1-c3e078d83722.mp4'));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 9.0 / 16.0,
        // Use [Video] widget to display video output.
        child: Video(controller: controller),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

And, I wanted to take away your misunderstanding... it works out of the box on all platforms, you don't need anything on users' computers.

On GNU/Linux however, it's a common & recommended practice to depend upon packages from the distribution (the same is done by media_kit).

Comment: I will try and will return after testing. Maybe it will be not so quick :)
Thank you!